# $scope variable not loading the values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, frontend

```
    $scope.loadSeletedTemplate = function () {
        $scope.itemEditor = document.getElementsByTagName("item-editor")[0];
        angular.forEach($scope.questionTypesList, function (item) {
            if ($scope.questionTypeText === item.Description) {
                $scope.selectedItemTemplate = {
                    IsNew: $scope.questionJson ? false : true,
                    ItemId: '',
                    ItemJson: $scope.questionJson,
                    ParentId: '',
                    TemplateId: item.TemplateID,
                    ItemEntityTypeID: 4,
                    ItemParentTypeID: 3,
                    UserID: ''
                };
            }
        });


        if ($scope.itemEditor.loadComponent) {

            $scope.itemEditor.loadComponent($scope.selectedItemTemplate, true);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $scope.loadSeletedTemplate();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

The $scope.selectedItemTemplate is not Loaded with the values. But when I declared in my code.
It's not loading the values. So This is not giving a proper response.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Would be helpful to have more context by providing the full html template and controller script. When is `$scope.loadSeletedTemplate()` called? On button click? On controller init? It also depends on how you are using this value as it might not be getting picked up by change tracking, triggering a digest cycle, or you are trying to access it from an isolate scope.

Comment: Thanks. It was failing in IF loop iself. Fixed it